# which arm board is best for real time purpose

Tags: ros, arduino#ros#raspberry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i want to connect some motors and sensors with one arm board and than connect it with pc. Here the pc will be doing all the heavy processing tasks while arm board will be just subscribing the joint trajectory values and than sending it to motors connected to its pins. In the same way it will be also reading the sensors and after calculating the encoder positions, it will be subscribing it to the main pc which will use that position for motion planning purpose.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256751/which-arm-board-is-best-for-real-time-purpose/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2017-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this is a possible board,
http://roscon.ros.org/2016/presentations/ROSCon2016_Turtlebot3_ROBOTIS.pdf

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR-Hardware

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2017-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0